# Função no Postgresql com update retorna erro quando atualizo 2 colunas

Tags: postgresql

Sou iniciante no postgresql e estou com uma dúvida que não consigo resolver. Fiz uma função simples no banco que atualiza um registro:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.teste(
    p_rec_id_transacao character varying,
    p_rec_valorA numeric)
RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
BEGIN 

     UPDATE financeiro_recebimentos SET rec_valorA=p_rec_valorA

 WHERE rec_id_transacao = P_rec_id_transacao;
 IF FOUND THEN
   RETURN TRUE;
 ELSE
   RETURN FALSE;
 END IF;    
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Funciona tudo certinho, mas quando adiciono um novo parâmetro e coloco no UPDATE retorna um erro quando chamo a função, sendo que a tabela esta definida corretamente e pior, quando rodo com o debug do PGadmin3 funciona:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.teste(
    p_rec_id_transacao character varying,
    p_rec_valorA numeric,
    p_rec_valorB numeric)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
BEGIN 

   UPDATE financeiro_recebimentos SET rec_valorA=p_rec_valorA, 
                                      rec_valorB=p_rec_valorB

   WHERE rec_id_transacao = P_rec_id_transacao;
   IF FOUND THEN
      RETURN TRUE;
   ELSE
      RETURN FALSE;
   END IF;    
END
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Quando chamo a função "SELECT teste('DJUNU',1.0,2.0)" retorna o erro:

HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Quem tiver a paciência responder, agradeço.

Comment: corrigindo:UPDATE financeiro_recebimentos SET rec_valorA=p_rec_valorA,   rec_valorB=p_rec_valorB

Comment: você pode corrigir algum detalhe da pergunta utilizando a opção editar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/220655/edit

Answer (score 1):

tente fazer assim:

```
SELECT teste('DJUNU'::varchar,1.0::numeric,2.0::numeric)
```

o erro que está dando, é que o sgdb não está encontrando uma função com esse nome e parametros

Comment: funcionou, obrigado!

Comment: não esqueça de marcar como resposta, obrigado